# What are some good sources of 3rd order gene expression data

Tags: rna-seq, public-databases, microarray

I need good sources of gene expression data in the form of 3rd order tensors. Typically the commonly available datasets are in the form of a matrix, for instance, $sample \times gene$ or $gene \times time$. I need good sources for 3-dimensional data, for example $gene \times sample \times tissue$ or $gene \times sample \times time$ ... etc.

Comment: Analysis packages rarely use that format for analysis, so find a nice time course dataset (there won't be many matching your needs) and reshape the matrix for it into the correct dimensions. As a aside, it's rarely useful to refer to a 3D matrix or 3 factor experiment as a "3rd order tensor" outside of machine learning.

Comment: I am working on tensor decomposition. I am interested in testing an idea on gene expression 3-d dataset. The papers who have worked on such gene expression dataset haven't made their data public. So...

Comment: @Satwik, you can ask them for the data and do a collaboration (if they and you wish).

Answer (score 1):

I familiar with the inflammatory bowel disease  which is quite complicated: 
It affects multiple sites and depending on when it appears it is different. So you can look at the GEO for microarrays and RNA-seq data of this disease and I'm sure you'll find datasets from the same patients from several tissues or time.

In this disease there is a [multi'omics project](https://ibdmdb.org/) that fits your needs. You can find (and download) data of high dimensionality: there are samples for the same time, tissue (but different locations), gene, over a period of time and for several omics (not only expression data).
The only problem is that there are some mistakes on the metadata.

However, I don't think they are usually described as 3rd order tensors and I doubt you'll find enough data to train a machine learning method.